# Calculating similarity between multiple ontologies (or ontology matching)

Tags: jena, semantic-web, owl, ontology, owl-api

The concise question is:

What Java Libraries do you usually use to measure/calculate the similarity/distance/relatedness between two or more Ontologies?

Details:

I have an OWL ontology X, and i want to calculate the similarity between this Ontology and another set of Ontologies A,B,C,D,.... to know which is the most similar Ontology to my X ontology,

I use OWL-API 5 to create my OWL ontology and i am quite satisfied with it, impressive performance, and easy to understand.

My ontology has Object Properties, Data Properties, Hierarchy of classes with different properties, Individuals with properties, etc.

Kindly, what Java Libraries do you usually use to measure/calculate the similarity/distance/relatedness? (i am solely interested in passing ontology X with ontologies A,B,C,..., and finding out which is the most similar).

I tried to test OntoSim (not much documentation). 
Thanks in advance for your time and suggestions.

If you know a technique or a method to do so and you do not know any Java library, kindly mention the name/paper of the technique you are using.

Sincere regards

Comment: What is the similarity of two ontologies ? X entail Y ? X include in Y ? difference of axioms of X and Y like in version management ?

Comment: Its not only as simple as entails, one cannot expect to find online an ontology that totally includes his own ontology. One of the main goals of using ontologies is re-usage. If an agent's ontology lacks something, it should be able to access different ontologies, extend own ontology etc. There are a lot of measures, some of them are hierarchical (simple distance) others are non-hierarchical content semantic similarity (depends on properties). My main research line is not about this, it is just a mere step in my work, that is why i am looking for an off-the-shelf java library to do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OntoSim proves to be a very powerful java library that is based on two publications:

- Jérôme David, Jérôme Euzenat, Comparison between ontology distances
  (preliminary results), in: Proc. 7th international semantic web
  conference (ISWC), Karlsruhe (DE), ( Amit Sheth, Steffen Staab, Mike
  Dean, Massimo Paolucci, Diana Maynard, Timothy Finin, Krishnaprasad
  Thirunarayan (eds), The semantic web, Lecture notes in computer
  science 5318, 2008), pp245-260, 2008
- Jérôme Euzenat, Carlo Allocca, Jérôme David, Mathieu d'Aquin, Chan
  Le Duc, Ondrej Sváb-Zamazal, Ontology distances for
  contextualisation, Deliverable 3.3.4, NeOn,    50p., 2009

I found the publications a good introductory to the subject of matter of distance measurements. From my experience with the library, if the developers of the library update its documentation and add more examples, OntoSim library will be used a lot by other developers, in its current status it is like a hidden gem.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try to use YAM++, an ontology alignment tool: http://yamplusplus.lirmm.fr/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is what you mean by "similar". There are many ways to be similar.

Actually, given your answer above, OntoSim should do the job for what you are asking, except that it usually compares only one ontology to another and I do not think that it uses imports.

If this is good enough for you, please post a minimal non working example and we'll try to make it work. You can start from the Example given at the bottom of this page http://ontosim.gforge.inria.fr/: it loads two ontologies and computes various similarities.

If you want, as suggested by @Galigator, to know if one ontology is equivalent to another one, you can iterate on their axioms and and see if the other ontology entails them.